# iTunes podcast connect

Tags: podcasts, mac-appstore

Has anyone successfully created a podcast on iTunes? I'm in Apple Hell : if I go to Podcast Connect, it lets me log in, then I choose "Podcast" as the type of content I want to create, and that takes me back to the Login page.

I gather my Apple ID has to be approved for content creation, but I cannot figure out how to do that.

There is also App Store Connect, but I cannot access THAT because it says

"To access App Store Connect, you must be enrolled in the Apple Developer Program or be invited by a user with the Legal role or Admin role in App Store Connect. Learn More."

Answer (score 2):

**The issue:**

You need to accept the Terms & Conditions for the iTunes Store.

**Why?**

When you attempt to login to http://PodcastsConnect.apple.com with an Apple ID that has not been **authorized for use** in the iTunes Store, you will get stuck in a loop (and thus, instead of logging into PodcastsConnect, you will be returned back the login screen).

**The solution:**

1. Login to the iTunes Store. (In iTunes: click "Store" in the top >
   Login. Accept the terms. On an iOS device: Settings > iTunes Store >
   Login. Accept the terms.) You don't need to enter a credit card!
2. Login at https://podcastsconnect.apple.com/
3. Submit your podcast feed.

Bonus: Don't forget to check out the awesome [Podcast Analytics](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/podcasts/videos)

Answer (score 1):

[Source](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/podcasts/overview)

You need to create an account on Apple's podcast management site: [itunesconnect.apple.com](https://itunesconnect.apple.com).

1. Click the  iTunes Connect Add podcast button at the top left of the iTunes Connect dashboard.
2. Enter your RSS feed into the provided text box and then click the “Validate” button.
3. A Feed Preview will load if you do not have any validation errors. Please take a moment and review your podcast artwork, description, general information (e.g. description, categories, etc), and episodes. Please see the Validation Errors section if you have any problems validating your podcast feed.
4. If everything within the Feed Preview is correct, click the “Submit” button.

Here's Apple's [Podcast Creation Help Site](https://help.apple.com/itc/podcasts_connect/#/itc1723472cb) that can walk you thru the process.